What order does the Windows Photo App use for images on the Desktop, and can this order be changed?
Within the Windows Photo App, there are left and right arrow buttons on the left and right sides of the app window, respectively.  These allow the user to leaf through several images in some order determined by the Windows Photo App.
When the images (say, a batch of .png files produced by simulation code) are opened with the Windows Photo App from within File Explorer, the Windows Photo App simply uses the order of the images within their folder in File Explorer.  This order is in turn determined by the column that the user selects — for example, "Date modified" or "Size."
However, when the images are saved to the Desktop and opened with the Windows Photo App from the Desktop, the order that the Windows Photo App uses is less clear.  It does not, for example, follow the order of the files within the Desktop folder in File Explorer.  What is this order and can it be changed?
